# What does $C^k$ at a single point mean?

Tags: real-analysis, differential-geometry, manifolds, differential-topology, smooth-manifolds

I'm reading textbooks on manifolds. I usually see a saying that "function $f$ is $C^k$ at a point $p \in M$". I am confused with this. What does this mean?

Furthermore if $f$ is $C^k$ at $p$, is it necessary that $f$ is $C^k$ in some neighborhood of $p$?

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: A function with $k$ continuous derivatives at $p$ is called a $C^k$ function. See http://mathworld.wolfram.com/C-kFunction.html

Comment: Continuously differentiable $k$ times.

Answer (score 3):

By definition, a function $f: M \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is $C^k$ if there exists a chart $(U, \text{x})$ around $p$ such that $f \circ \text{x}^{-1}$ is a $C^k$ function on the open set $\text{x}(U) \subset \mathbb{R}^n$. So if a function is $C^k$ at a point, it is necessarily true that the function is $C^k$ in some neighborhood of the point: that is because what you're actually doing is writing the function in local coordinates of the manifold in order to apply the definition of differentiability that is known for euclidean spaces, and that definition imply taking the difference between two values of a function in arbitrarily close points. That is why afterall, that for euclidean spaces, differentiable function are definied mostlty on open sets.

Comment: It's really the continuity of the $k^{\text th}$ derivative(s) that requires the $C^k$ property to hold on a whole neighborhood. If we just wanted $C^{k-1}$ and $k$-times differentiability at $p$, the $k^{\text th}$ derivative(s) may only exist at $p$ and nowhere else.

Answer (score 1):

It means the $k$th differential of the function $f$ is continuous at $p$. This  means the the function has to be differentiable around p but does not mean it is differentiable k times everywhere on the manifold (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differentiable_function)

Comment: You should modify the first sentence. The various $k$th partial derivatives need only be continuous *at* $p$. Yes, you're exactly right, but in the context of mappings on manifolds, ordinarily we worry only about $C^k$ on open subsets. Also, [this Wiki article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antiderivative#Antiderivatives_of_non-continuous_functions) may be more helpful for thinking about $C^1$ at a point but not in a neighborhood.